# MySQL - get max value of count

Tags: mysql, count, max

I'm trying to only select Nicknames with the maximum number of posts but I can't seem to be able to get it done...
Needless to say the code below doesn't work but this is what I got so far.

```
SELECT Person.Nickname FROM Posting, Person 
   WHERE Person.Nickname=Posting.Nickname 
   AND count(Posting.PostingID)=(select max(count(Posting.PostingID)))
   GROUP BY Person.Nickname 
   ORDER BY Person.Nickname ASC;
```

It would be great if someone could help!
I'm slowely but surely getting REALLY frustrated and I feel that my problem is something really easy that I'm just overlooking...

Thx in advance for your help!

Edit: 
This is under the assumption that there is more than one person with the maximum amount of posts.
For example: 
A might have 5 Posts, 
B might have 4, 
C might have 5 Posts 
and so on.

The output should then be: A,C,...

Comment: Unclear to me. Please add your expected output based on some sample input.

Comment: order by cnt DESC LIMIT

Comment: The output should be a list of the Nicknames of the people who posted the max amount of posts. 

These are the tables in question:
Person (Nickname, Firstname, Lastname, Password)
Posting (Nickname, PostingID, Time)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need person table you can get it from Posting

```
 SELECT Nickname FROM Posting GROUP BY .Nickname having  count(Posting.PostingID) = 
(SELECT count(Posting.PostingID) FROM Posting 
    GROUP BY .Nickname 
       ORDER BY count(Posting.PostingID) desc LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: The problem is that there is more than one person with the maximum amount of posts. For example: A might have 5 Posts, B might have 4, C might have 5 Posts and so on. The output would then need to be A,C ...